# PHP nested array yielding undefined index error - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sending a POST array to a controller. The array looks like such:

```
Array
(
[event] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ['publishStart'] => 2013-12-10
                ['eventStart'] => 2014-05-05
                ['eventEnd'] => 2014-05-10
                ['timeStart'] => 
                ['timeEnd'] => 
                ['location_id'] => 1
                ['id'] => 65774
            )
```

There are a few of these blocks, i.e. [event][1]. [event][2], etc. I'm attempting to run a foreach loop on $_POST['event'] and can confirm that on each iteration, $event contains the following:

```
Array
(
    ['publishStart'] => 2013-12-10
    ['eventStart'] => 2014-05-05
    ['eventEnd'] => 2014-05-10
    ['timeStart'] => 
    ['timeEnd'] => 
    ['location_id'] => 1
    ['id'] => 65774
)
```

Now, the problem. You can see in both above arrays there is a key called "id" with a corresponding value. Yet the following code returns a string of "undefined index" errors:

```
foreach ($_POST['event'] as $event)
{   
    echo $event['id'];
    exit();
}
```

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: just for debug, do a var_dump on $event instead of the echo $event['id']

Comment: Sorry if I did not make it clear enough, but both arrays above are nicely-formatted versions of both of your requests, direct output from var_dump. The full var_dump for $event is at http://pastebin.com/x1YrjdGc nd the full var_dump for $_POST is at http://pastebin.com/fa9zkTWa thanks!

Comment: There's probably atleast 1 `event`-block in your `$_POST`-array without an `id`-field.

Comment: Crazy thing though is that when I try to display a counter to show me how many times it's gone through the loop, it always stops after the first iteration. Does that matter?

Comment: Do you `var_dump` / `print_r` **exactly** in front of the loop?

Comment: Yep. Here's the FULL output of var_dump, labeled: http://pastebin.com/fPZ5Kfn1 ... I did the dumps of POST outside the loop, and the dump of $event inside the loop.

Comment: FWIW, it's not limited to the id field. If I try to echo anything, like $event['eventStart'] it still throws an undefined index error.

Comment: Are you using `print_r` instead of `var_dump` on your last paste? If so: Your indices seem to include the single quotes... so `echo $event["'id'"];` might work.

Comment: @ivan It's normal to stop after your first iteration due to the `exit();` statement.
just move it below the loop closing brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array indices seem to include the single-quotes.

Try

```
echo $event["'id'"];
```

Comment: Ugh, thank you so much! Elsewhere in the code before the variables got passed to POST the single-quotes were being escaped for some reason. I really appreciate it!